# FCM-Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'

Tags: python, django, firebase

I'm trying to use `fcm-django` in my `Django` app to use `Firebase` messages and notifications.

But when I try to initialize the firebase app it gives me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\rolla_django\settings.py", line 14, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport import requests
  File "D:\Python\rolla_django\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 37, in <module>
    import requests.adapters  # pylint: disable=ungrouped-imports
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.adapters'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've followed the [Official documentation](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#demo-javascript-client-project) for `fcm-django` as follows :

**requirements.txt**

```
Django
djangorestframework
django-extensions
pymysql
firebase-admin
fcm-django
requests
```

**Settings.py**

```py
from firebase_admin import credentials
import firebase_admin

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'fcm_django',
    'django_extensions',
    'accounts',
    'projects',
    'requests',
    'static_data'
]

cred = credentials.Certificate(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "rolla-9f502-firebase-adminsdk-wpo1z-31dba08f1e.json"))
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
    "DELETE_INACTIVE_DEVICES": False,
    "UPDATE_ON_DUPLICATE_REG_ID": True,
}
```

But still, I face the error when I try to run the project